# Simba Hbase ODBC Driver Connection Error

Tags: odbc, hbase

Hi I'am trying to create a DSN using Simba Hbase ODBC Driver 1.0.2 but it fails, I'am using Windows 2008 R2 64 bits and Hbase 0.96.
i have this error :

> Failure: [Simba][HBase] (40) Error with HTTP request, response code: 0

and in the log file i found this error:

> Expected HEADER=HBas but received HEADER=GET  from USER_IP

Any Help Pleaase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you started the HBase REST interface? If not, you'll see an error message like the one you've listed above. You can start the REST interface with the following command (depending on distribution):

hbase-daemons.sh start rest

This will start the REST interface on port 8080 by default.

Comment: Hi KylePorter! Yes this was the problem, I didn't start the Hbase Rest Interface. Now It works ! Thanks